# How to use only alphanumeric and backspace key on keyListener event in Java

Tags: java, swing

```
package com.man.practice;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    private char c = 'e';

    public MyPanel() {
        initComps();

    }

  JTextField t1=new JTextField(10);
  JLabel l1=new JLabel();




    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        l1.setText("Key Pressed");
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {l1.setText("keyReleased");}
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        l1.setText("keyTyped");
    }
    void initComps(){
        JFrame fr=new JFrame();
        fr.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        fr.add(t1);
        fr.add(l1);
        t1.addKeyListener(this);
        fr.setVisible(true);

    }
    public static void main(String[] s) {
       new MyPanel();
    }
}
```

In this program I want that only when I press any alphanumeric keys and backspace key then only my program should show effect not for all other keys.

Guys please help me how to do this.

Comment: `if (e.keyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {...}` and repeat for all the keys you want to use...

Comment: If you're intending to filter the text going into a `JTextField`, then `KeyListener` is the wrong choice and you should be using a `DocumentFilter`